# SSRS Using 2 Datasets in 1 graph but dataset being added in using expression wont group by same X axis

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a report that uses 2 datasets in a line graph;

- Dataset_2022/23
- Dataset_2019/20

The datasets are both grouped by the months of the year and they use the same column (MonthNameOfYear [January, Feb etc...]) to group by in each query. If I run the report using 1 dataset in the graph, it works as intended. When I go to add the expression `=SUM(Fields!ColumnName.Value, "Dataset_2019/20")`, it will add it as a new series value but will ultimately sum the entire 12 months into 1 figure and display that figure for each month ie. January 200, February 300, March 200 - Each month will display 700. The original dataset will still group by correctly and break it down by month.

Both datasets in SQL show results broken down by month as intended.

If I remove the SUM then it just doesn't show the series at all as it needs an aggregate. If I switch it to COUNT, then the figure is always 12 (Each month of the year).

[Not using aggregate will not display line]

[image]

[Using SUM will not break down by month]
[image]

How can I have it so that the series both follow the correct month of the year grouping? Is there a method where I can specify which grouping by column I want in the graph properties itself?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If your datasets contain a single value per month then this is quite simple. Here's quick example.

First I created 2 datasets `DataSetA` and `DataSetB` as follows

**DataSetA**

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (MonthNum int, Amount int)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
(1, 100),
(2, 200),
(3, 200),
(4, 200),
(5, 300),
(6, 600),
(7, 500),
(8, 400),
(9, 500),
(10, 800),
(11, 800),
(12, 900)

SELECT * FROM @t
```

**DataSetB**

```
DECLARE @s TABLE (MonthNum int, Amount int)
INSERT INTO @s VALUES 
(1, 150),
(2, 150),
(3, 200),
(4, 150),
(5, 400),
(6, 250),
(7, 300),
(8, 350),
(9, 400),
(10, 450),
(11, 450),
(12, 350)

SELECT * FROM @s
```

Next I added in line chart and dragged the `Amount` field in `DataSetA` onto the chart and dragged the `MonthNum` to the "Category Groups" pane

[image]

The chart works as expected with a single simple series

[image]

Next in the "Values" pane I added a new value by clicking the green `+` and selecting "Expression"

I set the expression to be a `LOOKUP()` to the second dataset (`DataSetB`)

```
=LOOKUP(Fields!MonthNum.Value, Fields!MonthNum.Value, Fields!Amount.Value, "DataSetB")
```

Now the design looks like this (after a bit of formatting to make it easier to see)

[image]

... and the final output looks like this...

[image]